Matching tenses together in a sentence
I'd like to ask which tenses work here.

I will relax now, when he is studying - correct sentence I'm gonna relax now during the time he is studying

I will relax now, when you studied- doesn't make sense, right? tenses don't match

I will relax now, when you have studied for 2 hours - this makes sense but only because I added "for 2 hours" without that present perfect also would make zero sense

I will do relax now, when you study- this makes sense it suggests repeated study unlike my first example



"I will ... " is unnatural.  In spoken English it is always contracted to "I'll".

Marta: gonna is not correct grammar. It's just spelling to reflect how we speak.

I'll relax as soon as he starts studying ...

You continue to put "now" in the wrong clause. When the condition has been reached or attained or realized, now goes in the subordinate clause: "I will relax, now that you have studied for two hours."  Alternative: "I will relax since you've studied (now) for two hours."

All your sentences suffer from the same problem.  You indicate time with "now" which when combined with the future "I will ..." means "starting from now".  But then contradict this with a time phrase "when ....", which means "(not now but) at a future time"
So all are non-idiomatic because they contain this contradiction.
The last one *"I will do relax" is ungrammatical, due to the use of "do".
You could probably rephrase with "while" or some other word, and omit "now".

I'm going to relax while he's studying.


I won't relax until he has studied for two hours.


I will relax only when he's been studying for two hours.

etc

Would there be any difference if I said "I will relax now while you are studying" vs "I will relax now while you study" or it changes nothing and both are fine?

Why do you still include "now"?    anyway, not much difference in that case with the word "study"
